Electric and magnetic field configuration that makes an electron trace the surface of a sphere
Can anyone suggest an electric and magnetic filed configuration that can make an electron trace the surface of a sphere? Has such a configuration been achieved experimentally?

The most straightforward approach would be to make a thin metal spherical shell. Mobile electrons in the metal can move freely. They are constrained by the shape of the metal. At a microscopic level, the constraint is created by the electromagnetic field of the nuclei and other electrons combined with the quantum mechanical behavior of electrons.
If you want to force the electron to follow a trajectory instead of just wander, use a stick made from an insulator. Put a charge on one end. Fasten the other to a pivot. Move the stick in the trajectory you desire.
If you want the electron to be in a vacuum, look at particle accelerators. They make particles trace a circle, which is a subset of a sphere. It would be complex, but something similar could be done over a sphere. Most particle accelerators use particles other than electrons.
You might also take a look at Tokomak fusion reactors. They have extremely hot plasmas in a large volume rather than a thin ring. Their purpose is not to make particles trace spherical paths. But you might build something similar that does.
